# URIs for QuickTime X

Tags: macos, video, streaming, http, quicktime

Apple lets you Stream video over HTTP with their new tech, but is there a URI scheme to open the .m3u8 files from a browser in Quicktime X? (ie. Open as a URL, rather than downloading and attempting to play the local file)

Answer (score 0):

You can register a URI on Mac OS X by adding to your info.plist.

Here's an example:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.test.m3u8</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>m3u8</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This is all assuming that the application has implemented the application:handleOpenURL method.

Comment: Which info.plist? Unfortunately this isn't really useful as I don't want to have to ask every user of my website to hack their plist files to make my site work!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution so that users of your website have their application automatically launch when they encounter your .m3u8 file?  You can't control how a user's browser will handle what content you send, it's entirely up to the browser.  If your browser doesn't know how to render the filetype it will always default to downloading the file (unless you have a specific URI and a handler assigned to manage that URI).  The closest you can get is to just ask users to open QuickTime manually and give them the URL to open (which streams the file).